# How do I escape the following command in mac terminal?

Tags: macos, bash, escaping, terminal

How do I get this command working in the command line?

```
grep "<!--#include  file="../../includes/" *.*
```

I know I can escape the "/" by doing "/" but I get problems with the "!--" and the " after file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single quotes for string literals in command line when you don't want the parameter expansion.

```
grep '<!--#include  file="../../includes/' *.*
```

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the pattern in single quotes. If you also want to make sure the string is treated as a literal, try with -F